# Get picture from EmbeddedResource in Forms project from Android project

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How would I get a picture from the EmbeddedResource in a Forms project from inside the Android project for a custom renderer?

In iOS I have already implemented this.

```
var imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromResource(Base1902iOS.PictureAssembly, Base1902iOS.MainAssemblyName + ".Resources." + control.Icon));
```

The FromResource method already gets the resource by name from the specified assembly. How would I do the equivalent in Android? *(Preferably also to be converted into an Android Bitmap.)*

This is for adding an icon to an Entry view in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JohnB - Though, I don't see any problem in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

C#

```
async void Testing(ImageSource icon)
{
    var renderer = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
    Bitmap photo = await renderer.LoadImageAsync(icon, Context);

    var iconfor = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(photo, 20, 20, true));
    Control.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, iconfor, null);
}
```

XAML:

```
<customControl:Entry Text="Lawrence" 
               HeightRequest="44" 
               Icon="{res:ImageResourceCustomControls.Forms.Test.Resources.test.png}"/>
```